# Heroku deploy error: No such middleware to insert after: ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord

My rails api app runs fine locally, but the app crashes when deployed to heroku. The app pushes to heroku successfully but with the warning "Detecting rails configuration failed", and launching the heroku console by running "heroku run rails console" shows the following error:

```
        10: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
         9: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:108:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
         8: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `app'
         7: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `synchronize'
         6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `block in app'
         5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:94:in `merge_into'
         4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:94:in `each'
         3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:95:in `block in merge_into'
         2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/configuration.rb:60:in `block in insert_after'
         1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:109:in `insert_after'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.1.3.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:162:in `assert_index': No such middleware to insert after: ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending (RuntimeError)
```

I've tried:

- uninstalling gems
- setting config.public_file_server.enabled to true in config/environments/production.rb
- updating ruby and rails and bundle updating my gems

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.. I had a line of code left over in application.rb when setting up omniauth:

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending, ActionDispatch::Cookies
```

Removing it solved the problem :)

Comment: Didn't you need this line of code for OmniAuth to work? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I ended up using `config.middleware.use` instead of `config.middleware.insert_after`.